# CSS and menu active state

Tags: css

How would I go about setting the menu so that the item to the right of the selected/active menu item does not have a background image.

Example with no selected state, just to show how the small 3px width separator, is added

```
ul li {
    background: url(nav-seperator.gif) no-repeat right top;
}
```

[image: no selected state]

Next, I need to add a selected state using a repeating background image:

```
li.active a, li a:hover {
    background: url(nav-active-repeat.gif) repeat-x;
}
```

Like the example below:

[image]

Although the part I want to remove is the part in red:

[image]

I would like it to look like this:

[image]

Ideally I would like to use only CSS and without adding the class to the next item.

I have created a basic version here: http://jsfiddle.net/6nEB6/3/

EDIT: I have added the print screen of the JSfiddle and the design so you can easily compare and will notice the small image to the right of the selected menu item.

Comment: I don't really understand your question.

Comment: Updated with a new image that should explain what I mean further

Comment: So you're saying that you want a menu that doesn't use images?

Comment: Sorry, John, I still don't understand. Maybe you want to rephrase your question?

Comment: I think his problem is the white 1px line next to the blue box because of his separator image.

Comment: actually what you want to know , do u want to remove the separator from the menu?

Comment: I have updated the question and JSfiddle, thanks

Comment: John, I suggest you take a look at my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Solution**

If by "item to the right" you mean the separator image, all you need to do is add a margin right or left that overlaps the image and add the missing pixels to the padding or margin
So if I had an initial padding of 21px my resulting CSS for on hover could be

```
li.active a, li a:hover {
    margin-left: -2px;
    padding-left: 23px;
}
```

Of course, there are other ways to overlap that image, but that's how I do it.
In your current example, this will not work, since the separator is in a different element and overlapping it would not render above it, but below it.

The example below will show you how to properly implement it.

---

**Example**

[Here's an example](http://jsfiddle.net/6nEB6/38/) using only two images: background and separator. The example also demonstrates how to use CSS classes properly, without having to add a new class for each new element.
If you want to add a background specifically for the first li element, ie. a selected background with a rounded corner just add this code

```
li.active:first-child a, li:first-child a:hover{
    background: url(...);
}
```

as this has a higher specificity, it will override the previous hover instructions for that element.

---

**Suggestions**

I would suggest you stopped using separate images for every navigator element. You might be better off with one background image and a separator.
Using image-only based navigation has several downsides, the biggest ones search engine crawlers and image quality, scaling and rendering in different browsers.

Comment: I use the same sprite image for each navigation element and ensure that the text is also read able for search engines. Also when I test your example in IE7 it doesn't work and causes a strange flicker on hover.

Comment: Mm, well I don't expect people to use IE7, or any other version of that crappy browser, except when they want to bang their head against the wall. IE never play nice with other browsers. Anyway, [here's the fix](http://jsfiddle.net/6nEB6/38/) for that. It's nice having a navigation without the need to go to an image editing software when you have to change the title. This enables easy editing. Like I said, there are many downsides using it the way you are.

Answer (score 1):

**This would be possible using the `+` combinator** (see http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#adjacent-sibling-combinators), but only if you switched it around so that the separator image sits to the left instead of to the right:

```
li 
{ background: url(nav-seperator.gif) no-repeat left top; }
li.active, li:hover
{ background: url(nav-active-repeat.gif) repeat-x; }
li:first-child
{ background: none; }
li.active + li, li:hover + li
{ background: none; }
```

The problem you get instead is now you don’t have a separator at the end. Of course, you could just add a dummy `<li>` to the end:

```
li:last-child
{ width: 10px; }
li:last-child:hover
{ background: none; }
```

Be advised, however, that `+` does not work in Internet Explorer 6, and `:last-child` does not even work in Internet Explorer 7 (the latter being easily solved by using `.last` instead).

**Personally, though, I would use Javascript to solve this.** It’s slightly too complex to be solved conveniently using only CSS right now.

If we had universal CSS3 support, it would be a different matter. Then we could easily add the rightmost separator in any number of ways (multiple backgrounds, `li:last-child::after`, etc.). Of course, sometimes you *can* rely on good CSS3 support, such as when you’re only targeting mobile WebKit.

Comment: Damn, why didn’t I see the obvious `margin-left: -3px` solution.

Comment: Yes but I see where your going with this way and maybe I can use it in the future. Thanks